# i am writing a shell script to find the sum, the average and the product of the four integers entered but i am getting an error can someone guide me

Tags: shell

the error i got is
./2ndques.sh: command substitution: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ./2ndques.sh: command substitution: line 6:` expr \ ( $dec * 1000 \ ) / 4'
Sum=

```
echo Enter four integers with space between
read a b c d
Sum=`expr $a + $b + $c + $d`
Avg=`expr $sum / 4`
Dec=`expr $sum % 4`
Dec=`expr \ ( $dec \* 1000 \ ) / 4`
Product=`expr $a \* $b \* $c \* $d`
echo Sum=$sum
echo Average=$avg.$dec
echo Product=$product
```

Comment: @harsh : When calculating i.e. the variable `Avg`, you are using a variable `$sum` which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Also you did not escape the parenthesis. You wrote `\ (`, which escapes the space, but leaves the prenthesis intact. You have to write either `\(` or `(` or `"("`.

Comment: i got it thank you for helping